# NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm receiving the following error when I try to load the page. I've tried some of the suggestions from other articles here on StackOverflow but I just can't hit on the solution. My code is below the error stack.

```
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1354)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:23104)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:24192)
    at resolveDep (core.js:24722)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

app.module.ts:

I've added in the import of the httpModule and added it to the imports array.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ApiAuthorizationModule } from 'src/api-authorization/api-authorization.module';
import { AuthorizeGuard } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.guard';
import { AuthorizeInterceptor } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.interceptor';
import { MemberComponent } from './member/member.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MemberComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JsonpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ApiAuthorizationModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'member', component: MemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard] },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's the page module - member.component.ts:

I know exactly what line of code trips the exception. It's the constructor. If I comment out the constructor the page will load.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Portfolio } from '../models/Portfolio';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-component',
  templateUrl: './member.component.html',
  providers: [Http, HttpModule]
})

@Injectable()
export class MemberComponent {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getPortfolios() {

        //return this.http.get('api/portfolio').map((r: Response) => <Portfolio><unknown>[] > r.json().data);
    }
}
```

Can you spot what I am missing? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be working with a relatively old angular version. So my first suggestion is to update your code base. For security, speed and 'ease of finding answers to questions'.

Second point. You are importing the `HttpModule` and the `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`. The `HttpModule` is deprecated, and you should not use this one anymore. Nevertheless, you should also never import both, so you need to remove the `HttpModule` from your `AppModule`.

Another issue is the `JsonpModule`, this as well has been deprecated, and the use case for this is now embedded inside the `HttpClient`, so you should remove this module as well.

After that, your `MemberComponent`. You are injecting `Http`. This is a service from the old deprecated `HttpModule`. You should replace that with the `HttpClient`. While using the `HttpClient`, you do not have to use the `.json()` anymore, because this is done automatically.

Also, you should not add the `Http` provider to the `@Component` definition, and you should -never- import a module in a providers array.

Last point, `@Injectable` on a component is redundant, because all components are injectable. This brings us to this result:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MemberComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ApiAuthorizationModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'member', component: MemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard] },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-component',
  templateUrl: './member.component.html'
})
export class MemberComponent {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getPortfolios() {
      return this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('api/portfolio');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre. I'm surprise to hear that I am working with an older version. I'm new to Angular though, perhaps I've just done something fundamentally wrong. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and this is the template project which is produced by selecting to create an Angular web application. I'd have thought that this would give me a relatively late version of Angular but perhaps not? How do I upgrade to the latest (stable) version of Angular? Thanks!

Comment: @YossiGeretz if you are using the angular cli as well, you can run `ng update @angular/cli` and  `ng update @angular/core`. What version are you running?

Comment: angular/common, angular/core, angular/http, angular/platform-browser: (7.2.15); rxjs, rxjs-compat (6.5.3); zone.js (0.8.29). (Not sure what that last one is, but it is listed under the npm folder along with the others.) Am I way out of date with these?

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your suggestions. As htn points out - HttpClient is imported from @angular/common/http, rather than @angular/http. With your cleanup instructions and that final detail from htn I was able to get this to work. Does my Angular version need to be upgraded or was I just using outdated syntax?

Comment: The latest angular version is 8 with 9 on the way, but version 7 is not much of a difference. I see you are also using the rxjs-compat module, which I also noticed with how you were constructing your observables. I suggest you remove this package, and check the guide [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) on how to upgrade your code base.

Answer (score 1):

You should inject `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`

Comment: Where do I do this? Here? constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { } I tried this. It generated import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http'; I have no idea what that is and now the web app won't start with a 404. On startup: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\***\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\***\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http'

Comment: htn - thanks so much for your help! I wish I could award both of you the checkmark for the answer because both of you gave me enough information that when I put it together I was able to get it to work.